# Nativescript 5.4.0 build fails with "couldn't find sbg-bindings.txt"

Tags: android, nativescript, circleci

Nativescript released 5.4.0 where hmr is enabled by default. After upgrade to 5.4.0, my nativescript cloud build as well as local build started breaking with following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Couldn't find '/home/circleci/repo/platforms/android/build-tools/sbg-bindings.txt' bindings input file. Most probably there's an error in the JS Parser execution. You can run JS Parser with verbose logging by executing "node '/home/circleci/repo/platforms/android/build-tools/jsparser/js_parser.js' enableErrorLogging".
    at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBindings(Generator.java:126)
    at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:97)
    at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:48)
```

The following is a relevant code snippet which has changed.

**package.json**

```
{
  nativescript: {
    id: "com.sample.drawer.app",
    tns-ios: {
      version: "5.4.0"
    },
    tns-android: {
      version: "5.4.0"
    }
  },
  description: "NativeScript Application",
  license: "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  repository: "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  scripts: {
    lint: "tslint "
    app/**/*.ts
    "",
    tsc: "tsc"
  },
  dependencies: {
    nativescript-theme-core: "~1.0.4",
    nativescript-ui-sidedrawer: "~5.0.0",
    rxjs: "~6.2.0",
    tns-core-modules: "^5.4.1"
  },
  devDependencies: {
    nativescript-dev-sass: "~1.6.0",
    nativescript-dev-typescript: "~0.7.0",
    nativescript-dev-webpack: "~0.18.0",
    tslint: "~5.11.0",
    typescript: "~3.2.2"
  },
  readme: "NativeScript Application"
}
```

**nsconfig.json**

```
{
  "useLegacyWorkflow": false
}
```

When useLegacyWorkflow is set to true, the build works fine but I need to move away from legacy workflow. If required complete logs can be found at https://circleci.com/gh/rakeshgirase/CloudBuild/106. Earlier successful build is which uses legacyWorkflow and passes  https://circleci.com/gh/rakeshgirase/CloudBuild/103.

Since I have not made any changes to the code, it seems something to do with the environmental settings.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like there's some error in the Static Binding Generator execution. Can you please try the following:
1. Add `--log trace` to your build command
2. After the build operation, can you execute `cd platforms/android && node 'build-tools/jsparser/js_parser.js' enableErrorLogging`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added --log trace and the logs can be found at `https://circleci.com/gh/rakeshgirase/CloudBuild/108`. I couldnt add `cd platforms/android && node 'build-tools/jsparser/js_parser.js' enableErrorLogging` after build as build fails.

Comment: Can you please replace the build command with: `tns prepare android (add all your options that you pass to build command here) && cd platforms/android && node 'build-tools/jsparser/js_parser.js' enableErrorLogging`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The build result is at https://circleci.com/gh/rakeshgirase/CloudBuild/109. It still fails and doesn't execute the part after && you mentioned in your last comment.

Comment: Please **always add a [mcve] into your question**. This is presently off-topic because it requires readers to follow links to external sites, which may be amended or deleted in the future.

Comment: I understand why you have downvoted the question but this is a different problem related with the whole project and nothing related to a specific file or code so specifying couple of files wont be right in this case.

Comment: I urge you to make it on-topic if you can - it may otherwise be put on hold, and then people will not be able to give you answers anyway.

Comment: @halfer would you like to take a look again? I have modified the question.

Comment: OK, thanks - I have cast a reopen vote.

Comment: Have you followed instructions (https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions), "./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps --configs"?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Yong. I didn't do update-ns-webpack so I will try it and will let you know.

Comment: Still got same error message:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was the following:

From the project root run

```
./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps --configs
```

This updates package.json and node_modules.

Then I removed the following folders.

```
node_modules, platform, hooks
```

And do a clean run

```
tns run android
```

Comment: In this case, I had to clear the cache so that the build runs fine. The build needs a fresh copy every time to get away with this error. Latest updates can be found at https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/1385